# how to determine when to increase parallelism of a single worker or increase workers in storm?

Tags: apache-storm, distributed-system

In storm web site([storm](http://storm.apache.org/2013/01/11/storm082-released.html)) wrirtes:

> The "capacity" metric is very useful and tells you what % of the time in the last 10 minutes the bolt spent executing tuples. If this value is close to 1, then the bolt is "at capacity" and is a bottleneck in your topology. The solution to at-capacity bolts is to increase the parallelism of that bolt.

What does "increase the parallelism of that bolt" mean? Add tasks? executors? workers?

How to determine when to increase parallelism of a single worker or increase workers in storm?

Comment: https://storm.apache.org/releases/1.0.2/Understanding-the-parallelism-of-a-Storm-topology.html

Answer (score 1):

Increase the number of workers. The reason is, that even if you have 4 workers and 10 tasks (bolt instances), the tasks will be parallelized only to the extent of 4. The remaining 6 tasks are going to have to wait for processing time. So increase the number of workers by either increasing the number of slots or by increasing the number of nodes that connect to Nimbus.